# Edit Taxonomy term in Drupal shows empty page

Tags: drupal-7, taxonomy

I have added few terms to Theme (structure -> Taxonomy -> Theme). When I tried to edit the term, it is showing empty page. Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

Comment: could you please give more information about this issue?

Comment: I am the Administrator. I should be able to edit the terms already added under Theme Taxonomy. On clicking edit option it displays a blank page. Recently noticed that "Modules" page is also displaying an empty page.

Comment: Got the solution. Due to some unnecessary code added to pathauto.inc file caused this issue. On removing the code, everything worked fine.

Comment: nice, lets post as an answers, to help people on future problems with this.